# Button size and padding within RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm attempting to create a a Heading + button similar to the Google Music App, e.g. where there is a "Songs" Header on the Left and then on the right there is a Button with the text "X more"..

I've using a RelativeLayout for the TextView and Button

My problem is that the button is taking up the size of the layout that contains the text the height is all wrong and the padding doesn't seem to do anything.

```
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        [REMOVED for clarity]

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/list_foreground"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/photos"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/photo_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/actionbar_background"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="test" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RelativeLayouts are designed to have children in the layout "relative" to each other. In other words, if you want the Button to the right of the Textview, you need to tell it.

Because you are aligning relative to the parent LEFT / RIGHT, it appears that things are "kind of" working.

You may be better off with a LinearLayout, depending on your needs. LinearLayouts use "orientation" not RelativeLayouts.

You should look over some tutorials (like this one: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/) but ultimately you will probably put your button in first and then your text view so that the textview content will wrap appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same effect as the Music App I ended up using a RelativeLayout but instead of a Button I'm using another TextView, this is giving the impression it's a button but it gives me more scope to format the background etc. I think just setup a OnClickListener in the code

```
         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/photo_title">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/photos"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/more_photo_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/actionbar_background"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="10 MORE"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```